# Cycript script to run app in background

Tags: ios, background-process, jailbreak, cycript

I have a `cycript` `backboardd` script that works great on `iOS 7` for modifying an app to continue running in the background.

```
app = [BKProcess processForPid:$PID];
alive = [[BKProcessAssertion alloc] initWithReason:7 identifier:"AppKeepAlive"];
[alive setFlags:0xF];
[sc addAssertion:alive];
```

This is all that's needed. However on `iOS 8` this does't work as `BKProcess` is now `BKSProcess` and `BKProcessAssertion` is now `BKSProcessAssertion` and they have different methods.
There doesn't seem to be a way to attach the assertion to the app like on `iOS 7`.

Can some please help me get this working under `iOS 8`.

Answer (score 1):

There is, however when I used this I simply used the initializer with the required `PID`.

```
- (id)initWithPID:flags:reason:name:withHandler:
```

Check out the [BKSProcessAssertion](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/BKSProcessAssertion.h#L42) header for reference.

If you want to see an implementation for reference, check out [MessageBox](https://github.com/b3ll/MessageBox/blob/master/SpringBoard.xm) (now deprecated, but for reference):

Comment: Thanks, however the init method returns a `BKSProcessAssertion` object who's `valid` property is `false`. I think maybe MessageBox was written for <iOS7. I think the assertion must be triggered somehow.

Comment: You need to also ensure that you've got the entitlements hacked to allow SpringBoard to assign BKSProcessAssertions as it's usually backboardd that does this.

https://github.com/b3ll/MessageBox/blob/master/Tweak.xmi#L38-L63